# Selection issue in big ndimension numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a big multidimension numpy array, that I created by converting lists, and when I try to select one specific entry I get this error :

```
tickGroups[0, 0, 0]

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-e8d1dd9db3ac> in <module>
----> 1 tickGroups[0, 0, 0]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

When I do tickGroups[0]

```
array([{'price': 239.99, 'size': 1, 'tick': 0, 'sizeInBTC': 0.004166840285011875},
       {'price': 237.43, 'size': 1500, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 6.317651518342248},
       {'price': 237.41, 'size': 1500, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 6.318183732782949},
       ...,
       {'price': 238.55, 'size': 800, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 3.353594634248585},
       {'price': 237.69, 'size': 5000, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 21.035802936598092},
       {'price': 237.98, 'size': 22774, 'tick': 1, 'sizeInBTC': 95.69711740482394}],
      dtype=object)
```

and tickGroups[0][0]

```
{'price': 239.99, 'size': 1, 'tick': 0, 'sizeInBTC': 0.004166840285011875}
```

tickGroups[:] returns the whole thing

```
array([array([{'price': 239.99, 'size': 1, 'tick': 0, 'sizeInBTC': 0.004166840285011875},
       {'price': 237.43, 'size': 1500, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 6.317651518342248},
       {'price': 237.41, 'size': 1500, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 6.318183732782949},
       ...,
       {'price': 238.55, 'size': 800, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 3.353594634248585},
       {'price': 237.69, 'size': 5000, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 21.035802936598092},
       {'price': 237.98, 'size': 22774, 'tick': 1, 'sizeInBTC': 95.69711740482394}],
      dtype=object),
       array([{'price': 237.78, 'size': 1111, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 4.67238623938094},
       {'price': 237.81, 'size': 5000, 'tick': 1, 'sizeInBTC': 21.02518817543417},
       {'price': 237.81, 'size': 5000, 'tick': 0, 'sizeInBTC': 21.02518817543417},
       ...,
       {'price': 244.48, 'size': 1400, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 5.726439790575917},
       {'price': 244.33, 'size': 2000, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 8.185650554577824},
       {'price': 244.21, 'size': 7500, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 30.71127308464027}],
      dtype=object),
       array([{'price': 244.08, 'size': 10000, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 40.970173713536546},
       {'price': 244.05, 'size': 7500, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 30.73140749846343},
       {'price': 244.25, 'size': 20, 'tick': 1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.08188331627430911},
       ...,
       {'price': 254.0, 'size': 2000, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 7.874015748031496},
       {'price': 253.83, 'size': 6, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.023637867864318637},
       {'price': 253.82, 'size': 6, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.023638799149003232}],
      dtype=object),
       ...,
       array([{'price': 17519.5, 'size': 10, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.0005707925454493565},
       {'price': 17519.5, 'size': 10066, 'tick': 0, 'sizeInBTC': 0.5745597762493222},
       {'price': 17529.5, 'size': 100, 'tick': 1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.005704669271798968},
       ...,
       {'price': 17429.5, 'size': 9905, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.5682893944175106},
       {'price': 17430.5, 'size': 4800, 'tick': 1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.2753793637589283},
       {'price': 17431.0, 'size': 500, 'tick': 1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.02868452756583099}],
      dtype=object),
       array([{'price': 17431.0, 'size': 1000, 'tick': 0, 'sizeInBTC': 0.05736905513166198},
       {'price': 17430.5, 'size': 2975, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.17067783482975243},
       {'price': 17431.0, 'size': 1278, 'tick': 1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.07331765245826401},
       ...,
       {'price': 17450.0, 'size': 1000, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.05730659025787966},
       {'price': 17458.0, 'size': 6000, 'tick': 1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.34368197960820257},
       {'price': 17460.0, 'size': 12549, 'tick': 1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.7187285223367698}],
      dtype=object),
       array([{'price': 17460.0, 'size': 145, 'tick': 0, 'sizeInBTC': 0.008304696449026346},
       {'price': 17460.0, 'size': 500, 'tick': 0, 'sizeInBTC': 0.0286368843069874},
       {'price': 17462.0, 'size': 100, 'tick': 1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.005726720879624327},
       ...,
       {'price': 17550.0, 'size': 197, 'tick': 0, 'sizeInBTC': 0.011225071225071225},
       {'price': 17549.0, 'size': 525, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.029916234543278818},
       {'price': 17544.5, 'size': 50, 'tick': -1, 'sizeInBTC': 0.002849895978796774}],
      dtype=object)], dtype=object)
```

So if I'm trying to select the first price 239.99 for example, I thought that tickGroups [0, 0, 0] would work, but I get the error above.
`np.shape(tickGroups)` returns

```
(16130,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array full of arrays filled with dictionaries, so tickGroups[0][0]['price'] should give you the price from the first one for example.
If you want the correct dimensions you should work again on the creation, nevertheless, there are dictionaries at the end, not lists.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's it ! Cheers !

Comment: Is it possible to select all the "prices" from one specific array for example ? When I try `tickGroups[0][:]['price']` I get : `IndexError: only integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices `

Comment: Only with a loop in my opinion, for example:
`[tickGroups[i][j]['price'] for j in range(len(tickGroups[0])) for i in range(len(tickGroups))]`
should give you a list with all the prices

Comment: You could drop the 'i' range and than you would have only one specific array, for example `tickGroups[100][j]['price'] for j in range(len(tickGroups[0]))`